# Redirection to home page

Tags: java, .htaccess, jsp, redirect

In jsp page am creating login page, it contains username and password fields, am storing username in session, and am validating fields, if everything correct it will be redirect to **Home page** *(home.jsp)*.

This all process happening successfully.

My question is, when i type url for login page, it come with ***localhost:2500/shashi/login.jsp***  url.

When it is redirect to home page, the url will be ***localhost:2500/shashi/home.jsp***. its correct.

But suppose after log in, if session is not expired,

if i type ***localhost:2500/shashi/login.jsp*** login url, it should redirect to **home** i.e ***localhost:2500/shashi/home.jsp***

How do i achieve this?
java is server side code. web-server jetty

Comment: Check in your servlet if user object present in session redirect user to `home.jsp` page.Hope you are doing session invalidate when user logout .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect to another page when already authenticated user accesses login page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239925/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-when-already-authenticated-user-accesses-login-p)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think about something simple like this:

```
if(request.getSession(false).getAttribute("username") == null){
    response.sendRedirect("/home.jsp");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%  if(request.getSession(false).getAttribute("username") == null) {

        %>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/home";
        </script>
        <%          
    }
%>
```

Try this code insert at your **header.jsp** file, if not present header file then put in jsp file