# JSF Redirect without Managed Bean

Tags: jsf, redirect

I am trying to use JSF as a pure front-end tool. Is it possible for me to submit a form and based on the outcome of that form redirect to a different page? In this case, I have a back-end service that returns the outcome in the result variable. Depending on "result.success", I want to navigate to the appropriate page/view. Here is my JSF source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:r="http://mycustomtags.com/tags"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
  <head>
    <r:myService service="adminlogin" namespace="result" params='{"dummy":"Dummy Value"}' />
  </head>
  <body>
    #{result}
    <f:viewParam name="redirectPage" value='#{(result.success)?"success.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" : "sample-login.xhtml?IncludeViewParams=true"}' />
    output:#{redirectPage}
    <h:form method="post" action="sample-login.xhtml">
        <input name="token" type="hidden" class="input-block-level" value="34857349850" />
        <input name="email" type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="email" />
        <input name="password" type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="password" />
        <h:commandButton action="#{redirectPage}" value="Login" />
    </h:form>           
  </body>
</html>
```

I need to navigate to success.xhtml. I don't want to use "faces-config.xml". Any ideas? Here is my JSF code. By the way, this is does not work because action parameter in "h:commandButton" expects a MethodExpression.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any easy way to preprocess and redirect GET requests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294651/is-there-any-easy-way-to-preprocess-and-redirect-get-requests)

Comment: This does not work for me because it uses a Managed Bean in the backend. I need a solution that is purely view based that means I cannot call bean methods or trigger events.

Comment: Create a custom tag which does the very same job.