# How to perform navigation in preRenderView listener method

Tags: jsf-2, navigation, listener, prerenderview

I'm starting from [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for)

I have a pre render view event listener:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{loginBean.performWeakLogin()}" />
</f:metadata>
```

which invokes the following method:

```
public String performWeakLogin() {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    String parameter_value = (String) facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("txtName");

    if (parameter_value != null && parameter_value.equalsIgnoreCase("pippo")) {
        try {
            return "mainPortal";
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and the following navigation rule:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/stdPortal/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>mainPortal</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/stdPortal/stdPages/mainPortal.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

However, it doesn't perform the navigation. It works when I use a command button as follows:

```
<p:commandButton ... action="#{loginBean.performWeakLogin()}"  />
```

Comment: Note that I edited and changed the incorrectly used term "implicit navigation" to "navigation" throughout your question. With implicit navigation is meant that there's no `<navigation-case>` been used. E.g. just returning the `to-view-id` directly as outcome as in `return "/stdPortal/stdPages/mainPortal.xhtml";` or `handleNavigation(fc, null, "/stdPortal/stdPages/mainPortal.xhtml")`.

Comment: @BalusC  Thanks I thought the opposite! My fault!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Navigation based on a method's return value is only performed by components implementing [`ActionSource2`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/ActionSource2.html) interface and providing an attribute taking a `MethodExpression` for that, such as `action` attribute of [`UICommand`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UICommand.html) components, which is queued during *Apply Request Values* phase and invoked during *Invoke Application* phase.

The `<f:event listener>` is merely a [component system event](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/ComponentSystemEvent.html) listener method, not an action method. You need to perform the navigation manually as follows:

```
public void performWeakLogin() {
    // ...

    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(fc, null, "mainPortal");
}
```

Alternatively, you can also send a redirect on a given URL, which is more useful for the case you don't want to navigate internally, but externally:

```
public void performWeakLogin() throws IOException {
    // ...

    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/stdPortal/stdPages/mainPortal.xhtml");
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) is a better place for the job of performing request based authorization/authentication.

#### See also:

- [Is there any easy way to preprocess and redirect GET requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294651/is-there-any-easy-way-to-preprocess-and-redirect-get-requests/)

Comment: thanks as the usual. My problem starte d with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103844/jsf-read-post-param-and-skip-login. Where i have to manage a lot of situation so i think that the use of backingbean is enough to check user, but i go to investigate with servlet filter.

Answer (score 1):

I use JBoss 7 with JSF 2.1. The solution from BalusC was redirecting to the JBoss default error page, even though I had already set the default error page in the web.xml‎‎

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/myapp/404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

To redirect to my own error page, I used the response to send the error:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
try {
    response.sendError(404);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
facesContext.responseComplete();
```