# Obtaining FacesContext within xhtml view with JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I am trying to migrate an application from RichFaces to PrimeFaces 5.0 and upgrade JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.2. Earlier we had `.jsp` pages which contained below piece of code.

```
<%
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Login login = (Login) fc.getELContext().getELResolver().getValue(fc.getELContext(), null, "login");
    if (null == login.getEmailAddress()) {
        response.sendRedirect("./");
    }

%>
```

Now we changed every `.jsp` page to `.xhtml` and as expected the above piece of code would not fit in the xhtml view. I tried searching replacement for the above functionality in view but unfortunately could not find anything regarding same. I also tried to put the above line of code within `<!CDATA`, [not sure whether its a right way], as below:

```
<![CDATA[
<%
     FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
     Login login = (Login)fc.getELContext().getELResolver().getValue(fc.getELContext(), null, "login");
     if (null == login.getEmailAddress()) {
         response.sendRedirect("./");
     }
%>       
]]>
```

and as expected that didn't even work well.

How else I would be able to achieve this within `xhtml`? Will this be possible or should I be going for some other way to do this?

**Note - The application is a Single Page Application**

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106418/how-to-perform-navigation-in-prerenderview-listener-method

Comment: @JasperdeVries That really helped much bro. Would you like to add it as answer? Or will be closing this question as possible duplicate.. :)

Comment: Best way is to close as duplicate (good for SEO).

Comment: @JasperdeVries I agree.. Thanks much once again.. :) Have a great time.. :)

Comment: By the way, you know PrimeFaces 6.1 is available right?

Comment: @JasperdeVries Yea I do bro.. But due to some materialize-theme selection for the application, I had made lot of changes editing `Primefaces 5.0.jar`, before knowing the existence of `Primefaces 6.x`. Since, the duration is very less for delivery of 1st phase, I was not able to upgrade this. Hopefully, will upgrade in future.. :)