# Avoid back button after logging in on JSF web application

Tags: jsf, browser, jsf-2.2, back-button

I want to avoid back button after user has logged in JSF application. I am able to achieve this functionality after I log out but not after logging in.
For logout purposes I have used setheader method given here in the answer but it doesn't work to avoid back button after I log in.

[Avoid back button on JSF web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305718/avoid-back-button-on-jsf-web-application)

An answer without using javascipt would be better

Comment: Use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106418/how-to-perform-navigation-in-prerenderview-listener-method. Just check if the user is loggedin, check the current page and if already logged in, make it stay on the same page or go to the homepage or...

Comment: Using the filter that I tried previously it i working sometimes and sometimes not, Why is that happening?

Comment: Most likely because there is a bug in the filter code