# Limitations of using a PhaseListener instead of a Servlet Filter for authorization

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, authorization, servlet-filters, phaselistener

I'm currently using a `PhaseListener` as below to perform user authorization.

```
private PhaseId phaseId = PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW;

@Override
public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {

    FacesContext fc = event.getFacesContext();
    boolean isOnAllowedPage = false;
    String[] allowedPages = choseRightPages(); // chose pages for role

    for (String s : allowedPages) {
        if (fc.getViewRoot().getViewId().lastIndexOf(s) > -1) {
            isOnAllowedPage = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!isOnAllowedPage) {
        NavigationHandler nh = fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
        nh.handleNavigation(fc, null, "prohibited");
    }
}
```

It does what I want, however I don't see it being listed in [How to handle authentication/authorization with users in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965708/how-to-handle-authentication-authorization-with-users-in-a-database) and [this Coderanch topic titled "authorization with phaselistener problem"](http://www.coderanch.com/t/434445/JSF/java/solved-authorization-phaselistener) also mentions the following:

> You shouldn't couple authorization that tight with JSF. Better make use of container managed authentication and/or a simple filter acting on an url-pattern covering the protected pages.

I don't exactly understand the limitations of using a `PhaseListener` instead of a `Filter` when performing user authorization. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: If you down vote. Can you add comment why you think it's a bad question?

Comment: Generally, questions asking for opinions ("why should I") instead of about concrete technical problems, are considered off topic on Stack Overflow and therefore likely to be downvoted. Even if it was an acceptable question, you'd better add links to support those "vague reasons" instead of making them yet more vague by not referencing them with links at all. Oh, this is not a Java SE problem, so the `[java]` tag is a wrong suit too and attracts only folks who only think "wtf is he talking about?" when seeing this subjective JSF-specific question with code which doesn't make sense to them.

Comment: @BalusC As far as I know you are much experienced user of stack. And also honorable person in JSF. Can you edit my question to acceptable condition.

Comment: I desubjectivized the question and posted an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `PhaseListener` is only fired on a JSF request (i.e. a HTTP request which invoked the `FacesServlet`). It's not fired when a non-JSF request is executed and thus exposes a potential security leak on non-JSF requests. A servlet `Filter` can be fired on every single HTTP request, regardless of the target servlet.

In other words: HTTP request authorization should not be tied to having the `FacesContext` available, but to the `ServletRequest` available. Always try to authorize as "low level" as possible.