# JSF 2.0 call server side method on page load

Tags: java, jsf-2

let me give you an idea about how the system works.

I am using JAAS login module for login and role management.  I can access specific pages depending on the role i have.

I type my url in the address bar, hit enter.

The login page appears and after correct login, it redirects me to the correct page(for now lets call it page1.jsf).

I want to call a server side method on page load.

Can you help me please?

** EDIT **

Assume i have to access page1.jsf which is accessible to role1 only.

In the address bar, i type http://localhost:8080/myapp/page1.jsf

JAAS shows up the login page and after correctly inputting the credentials, i am redirected to page1.jsf

As soon as page1.jsf is requested or on page load, i want to call a server side method from my class to reload page1.jsf

Comment: See this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5522702/620338)

Comment: @MattHandy can you give more information about the AjaxBehaviorEvent? i have to reload my page several types to see all the contents that should have been displayed

Comment: You don't need this here. Maybe you need to update the whole page from your ajax call with the attribute `update="@all"`.

Comment: @MattHandy update attribute not found

Comment: Sorry, the plain jsf ajax attribute is correctly named `render` and not `update`.

Comment: @MattHandy it is still not working

Comment: Then please post the code you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using JSF 2, you can use the above page snippet:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  ... >
 <f:view contentType="text/html">
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{permissionManager.checkRoles}" />
    <f:attribute name="roles" value="ROLE" />

  ...
  </f:view>
</html>
```

you can add an attribute containing the role and in the `PermissionManager.checkRoles()` perform redirect to the corret page.

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
class PermissionManager { 
  ...
  public void checkRoles(ComponentSystemEvent event) {

       String acl = "" + event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("roles");
       //Check user role
       ...
       //Redirect if required
       try {

        ConfigurableNavigationHandler handler = (ConfigurableNavigationHandler) context
                .getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
        handler.performNavigation("access-denied");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    }

   }

}
```

Check out this [example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-prerenderviewevent-example/)
and take a look at this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488211/jsf-how-to-hit-a-bean-method-and-redirect-based-on-a-get-variable)

Comment: @sameer what is exatly the problem you get?

Comment: yes but it is not working.. it is not calling the preRenderView

Comment: You could try to put `<f:event>' immidiatly after `<f:view>`

Comment: what should i put in the viewparam when i do not have anything?

Comment: I use 'ANY' to point out that anyone can access the page, in this case you skip the permission check.

Comment: @sameer, since you already have your resource protected and authenticating properly. No need to check for roles again. Just simply, add <f:view>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{managedBean.someMethod}" />    and in your managedBean, try this   public void someMethod(ComponentSystemEvent event){ System.out.println("preRenderView called"); }

Comment: @Ravi thank you, i tried with <f:metadata> and it worked :) will be marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this works. Instead of accessing a jsp or jsf page, you can also access Servlets. So create a new servlet. E.g.:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class TestServlet
 */
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public static void yourMethod() {
         // do something useful
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        yourMethod();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Then create a new entry in the web.xml file, in order to map the Servlet to /.

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>TestServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>your.packages.TestServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/TestServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

After this, you should be able to call `localhost:8080/TestServlet` which then calls your method.

Comment: no servlet is to be used mate. I just want to call my server side method as soon as the page is requested/loading