# JSF: Instantly execute bean instead of xhtml file on particular URL

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I am creating an activation, triggered after clicking an URL in an e-mail from registration.
I would like to execute my bean Activate.java immediately, instead of creating an xhtml page with something like #{validate}.

I do not need any xhtml file because the user will be redirected to login.
What is the best way of achieving this?

Note, I am using JSF 2.0.

Comment: So, in short, the flow is User receives mail > User clicks link > User arrives to the normal login page but the account is activated? This url has a parameter to define the activation or any kind of generated code that defines which account must be activated, right?.

Comment: Well, maybe not the login page but a page with some successtext. But that means I could just load this successpage and run the validation. So in conclusion I have asked a rather dumb question, I can just trigger the action at the destinationpage.

Comment: Well, no question is dumb. I was going to suggest something similar to what BalusC just suggested, I'd go that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

```
@WebServlet("/activate")
public class ActivationServlet extends HttpServlet {

   @EJB
   private ActivationService service;

   @Override
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
       String key = request.getParameter("key");

       // ...

       response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
   }

}
```

This will be invoked when you call `http://localhost:8080/contextpath/activate?key=42`.

You'll only miss JSF validation facility as possible with `<f:viewParam>`. What do you want to do if key is missing or invalid?

Comment: Great, this is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. I think this is a cleaner way then calling activation from the destination page. Thanks for your fast and complete answer.

Comment: Regarding your question about validation facility, my only issue would be the escaping of potential malicious GET-parameters. This would indeed be provided when using `<f:viewParam>`. Would StringEscapeUtils from Apache.commons be the way to go here, or should I stick with a preceding xhtml file?

Comment: That's not exactly a problem as long as you use parameterized queries. The problem is more, what if the key is missing or non-existent? Wouldn't you rather show an error message instead of redirecting to login page? See for example also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488211/jsf-how-to-hit-a-bean-method-and-redirect-based-on-a-get-variable/7488313#7488313

Comment: Perhaps that would be a more appropriate way to inform the user, yes. I hadn't even considered this possibility. Thanks for your time and great input!