# JSF: call backing-bean method without rendering the page (using URL parameters)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is it possible to use a **JSF** (PrimeFaces) page in the following fashion ? :

1. external application (not **JSF**-based) does an **HTTP GET** with **URL** parameters
2. **JSF** page reads those parameters (e.g. as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724428/how-do-i-process-url-parameters-on-page-load-using-primefaces)) and invokes a backing bean business method, without rendering anything to the user's browser
3. The user is transparently sent to a page corresponding to the navigation outcome of the backing bean method invoked in step 2.

In other words, the **PrimeFaces** page of step ***2*** is involved only for the side effect of calling the backing-bean business method and is never displayed. The user after clicking on a link on the external application of step ***1*** lands in the page of step ***3***.

Comment: Maybe you could define a `preRenderView`. Other than that I see few options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`<f:viewParam>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/viewParam.html) to set GET parameters as bean properties and use [`<f:event>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/event.html) to execute a bean action and use [`NavigationHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/NavigationHandler.html) to perform navigation programmatically.

View:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" />
    <f:viewParam name="bar" value="#{bean.bar}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.action}" />
</f:metadata>
```

Bean:

```
public void action() {
    // ...

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    NavigationHandler navigationHandler = context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
    navigationHandler.handleNavigation(context, null, "outcome");
}
```

Note that, depending on the concrete functional requirement, JSF might not necessarily be the right tool for the job. I'd investigate if you couldn't better use a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) or even a plain [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) for the purpose.

#### See also:

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for)
- [Hit a bean method and redirect on a GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488211/jsf-how-to-hit-a-bean-method-and-redirect-based-on-a-get-variable)