# How to invoke JSF backing bean method from link/non-faces-request

Tags: jsf-2

The use case is calling a method on a JSF 2.x Backing Bean directly from a hyperlink (Non-Faces-Request). What is the best way to do this?

I imagine to do something like this:

The Link:

```
http://localhost/show.xhtml?id=30&backingbeanname=loaddata&method=load
```

The Backing Bean:

```
@Named (value = "loaddata")
public class DataLoader {

     public void load(int id){ ... }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`<f:viewParam>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/viewParam.html) in the target view to set GET parameters as bean properties and use [`<f:event type="preRenderView">`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/event.html) to invoke an action on them.

In `show.xhtml`:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.id}" required="true" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.load}" />
</f:metadata>
<h:message for="id" />
```

In managed bean:

```
private Integer id;
private Data data;

public void load() {
    data = service.find(id);
}
```

Note that in the above example the URL `http://localhost/show.xhtml?id=30` is sufficient. You can always set more parameters as bean properties and have one "God" bean which delegates everything, but that's after all likely clumsy.

Also note that you can just attach a [`Converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) to the `<f:viewParam>` (like as you could do in `<h:inputText>`). The `load()` method is then most likely entirely superfluous.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.data}" 
        converter="dataConverter" converterMessage="Bad request. Unknown data."
        required="true" requiredMessage="Bad request. Please use a link from within the system." />
</f:metadata>
<h:message for="id" />
```

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2 - Processing GET request parameters](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters)
- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for/6377957#6377957)

Comment: Although the solution from BalusC invokes the method on the bean but it does not trigger jsf navigation. After a while I found this solution which covers exactly my use case:[link]http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/latest/reference/en-US/html_single/#viewaction

Comment: @user1866929: you didn't state that you need navigation. For that, head to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530651/jsf-call-backing-bean-method-without-rendering-the-page-using-url-parameters/13530836#13530836 Note that JSF 2.2 will come with a similar `<f:viewAction>`.