# Double dispatching in jsf

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Is it possible in Mojarra-2.1. If I do dispatching to another view from the action method by clicking action buttons:

```
<h:commandButton value="dispatch" action="#{myBean.action()}" />
```

The bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean{

    public String action(){
        //do some
        return "view";
    }
}
```

my browser then recieve the content of the view `view`. The view `view`, in turn contains the following:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

      <f:metadata>
            <f:event listener="#{viewBean.doDoubleDispatch()}" type="preRenderView" />
      </f:metadata>
</html>
```

where

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ViewBean{
    public String doDoubleDispatch(){
        //do
        return "finalView";
}
```

After invoking the `doDoubleDispatch` method I didn't see the content of `finalView`. But If click an `actionButton` which invokes the method it will work perfectly fine.

So, such things are not possible in Mojarra-2.1, aren't they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<f:event listener>` does **not** support navigation case outcomes.

Only the JSF 2.2 `<f:viewAction action>` does. Perhaps you're confusing with it.

You need to make it a `void` method and navigate/redirect manually.

```
public void doDoubleDispatch() {
    // ...

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    NavigationHandler navigationHandler = context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
    navigationHandler.handleNavigation(context, null, "finalView");
}
```

That said, the `<f:event>` doesn't necessarily need to end up in `<f:metadata>`. That's only for self-documentary purposes done when used together with `<f:viewParam>`. It was during the JSF 2.0/2.1 era actually abused to be able to invoke a bean method after all view parameters are been set. JSF 2.2 therefore introduced the `<f:viewAction>` to fill this gap, which in turn indeed requires being placed in `<f:metadata>`.

#### See also:

- [Hit a bean method and redirect on a GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488211/hit-a-bean-method-and-redirect-on-a-get-request)
- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for)

Comment: Just to make sure, is something like `navigationHandler.handleNavigation(context, null, "finalView?faces-redirect=true");` going to be possible? I mean to perform redirecting instead of dispatching...

Comment: Yes. Alternative is `ExternalContext#redirect()` if you don't care about configurable (implicit) navigation cases.

Comment: I just have noticed the the url in the browser's line get changed when I perform such dispatching. Is it possible to stay address the same?

Comment: That will only happen when you're redirecting, not when you're dispatching. Apparently you've chosen to send a redirect. Perhaps food for read as it surprises me that you're wondering about this even though you explicitly used the proper terminology in the 1st comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-navigate-in-jsf-how-to-make-url-reflect-current-page-and-not-previous-o and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277366/what-is-the-difference-between-redirect-and-navigation-forward-and-when-to-use-w/