# How to load data from backing bean after a redirect

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

When I do not use the `<redirect/>` tag in `faces-config.xml`, it does not update the browser URL, but the data is loaded successfully from the backing bean. When I use `<redirect/>`, the browser URL is updated, but the data is not loading from backing bean. How do I load the data from backing bean in this case?

Comment: could you please show the navigation rule. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `faces-redirect=true` in your navigation URL
For example

```
<h:form>
     <h:commandLink value="MyValue" action="MyPage?faces-redirect=true" />
</h:form>
```

Without define `<redirect/>` in your `faces-config.xml`
Now

1. The browser URL will be updated
2. The data is loaded successfully from the backing bean.

Comment: This isn't exactly what the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

JSF submits the form to the current page instead of to the target page and therefore the URL shown in your addressbar will always be *one request behind*.

Example:

```
Base-URL: example.org/index.jsf  // now we navigate to home.jsf
URL: example.org/home.jsf | Addressbar: example.org/index.jsf
// navigate to content.jsf
URL: example.org/content.jsf | Addressbar: example.org/home.jsf
// and so on
```

By using the the `faces-redirect=true`-parameter you're telling the servlet to re-route your request so that the addressbar gets updatet to the actual site you're on.
This behavior is especially wanted if the user should be able to bookmark this site explicitly.

So the first question would be: should this page be bookmarkable?
If so you'll have to use the redirect method either by creating a navigation rule in `faces-config.xml` (like you did) or you could use the implicite navigation by telling your action-component (commandLink/Button) the destination-viewId and append `?faces-redirect=true` to it.
If there is no need for bookmarking this page (or any other kind of operation where a GET-request is needed) you could waive to mess around with this and just stick with the standard POST-request.

Cheers

Comment: The explanation in your 1st paragraph is technically wrong. It's not because JSF is using POST. It's just because JSF submits the form to the current page instead of to the target page.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the loading job in (post)constructor of the backing bean associated with the target page, if necessary based on some request parameters.

E.g.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {

    private Data data;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        data = loadItSomehow();
    }

    // ...
}
```

If the target page references the bean by `#{bean}`, then it will be automatically constructed and you can just do all the job in the constructor or `@PostConstruct` method or even a listener method attached to `<f:event type="preRenderView">` if you happen to have `<f:viewParam>` instead of `@ManagedProperty`.

#### See also:

- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-make-url-reflect-the-current-page-and-not-the-previous-one)
- [JSF 2: invoking managed bean directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488832/jsf-2-invoking-managed-bean-directly/13492293#13492293)
- [ViewParam vs @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id/4889226#4889226)